# Emulating concurrency or multi threading in WCF C# application

Tags: c#, wcf

I am developing an Service-Oriented based application for Hotel Reservation System using WCF architecture. It has following 3 three components:
1. WCF Service that has Service and Data contracts for invoking moudules of room reservation.
2. WCF Host that keeps log of service access by client
3. WCF client that has UI for Hotel Reservation.

I am looking for guidelines to implement concurrency in my application having following features:
1. Only one request shall be entertained at the time. 
2. If more than one requests are received, then these should be synchronized using locks/mutex/semaphores.

Coding guidelines shall be helpful.

Comment: Do the clients using the service expect an answer directly? Because this won't scale and with many requests, if they take long enough clients might encounter timeouts while waiting for their turn. You might be better of using some kind of queue

Comment: But, there are options of concurrency control in single mode to allow multiple clients requests. I am more concerned of how these requests can be handled synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the allocation issue of the external resources, such as the database access, the I/O for on the single file. WCF supports transaction and transmitting it on the client-side. We are capable of locking the access to the database by using transaction when another client attempt to access it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transactions-overview
Moreover, we can also use the shared lock which locks the service instance, occupying all the resource lest the other instance access the service, please refer to the below code.

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
class MyService : IMyContract
{
 public void MyMethod()
 {
 lock(typeof(MyService))
 {
 ...
 MyResource.DoWork();
 ...
 }
 }
}
static class MyResource
{
 public static void DoWork()
 {
 lock(typeof(MyService))
 {
 ...
 }
 }
}
```

Please refer to the below link, Chaper8(concurrency management), resources and services, deadlock avoidance.
https://ashishmit99.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/oreilly-programming-wcf-services-3rd-edition-aug-2010.pdf
Here is an official document relates to Concurrency mode, aiming to solve access conflict from the multiple users.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/sessions-instancing-and-concurrency

Comment: What I understand is, scope of implementing concurrency is quite limited and restricted to different instances of clients?